# Criar uma lista e inserir no banco os dados da planilha ao importar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, dotnet-cli

Eu tenho um método `protected void importar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` e dentro dele eu verifico se o arquivo foi selecionado, e valido a extensão do arquivo. Esse sistema é uma sistema de importação de arquivo de uma planilha em excel, que salva os dados da planilha no banco, entretanto, quando vou importar o arquivo, demora demais, ao invés de trabalhar no código com disco, banco e memoria.

Eu estava pensando em fazer uma list com um insert, ai eu só iria trabalhar com a memória e o banco. Existe um código que eu posso fazer esse processo até mesmo para customizar o tempo? E gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade em cima do meu código, utilizar o serviço do windows para não sobrecarregar e deixar lento no momento da transmissão da importação do meu arquivo.

```
protected void importar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
//Verifica se um arquivo foi selecionado
if (selecionarArquivo.HasFile)
{
//Valida a extensão do arquivo:
if (Path.GetExtension(selecionarArquivo.FileName) != ".xlsx" && Path.GetExtension(selecionarArquivo.FileName) != ".xls")
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "Erro", "<script>alert('Somente arquivos em excel')</script>");

else
{
if (selecionarArquivo.FileContent != null)
{
string Excel = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + selecionarArquivo.FileName;
selecionarArquivo.SaveAs(Excel);
DataTable Dados = DadosExcel(Excel);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

ds.Tables.Add(Dados);

if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
{
bool layoutValido = VerificaLayout(ds);
if (!layoutValido)
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "Erro", "<script>alert('Layout do arquivo fora do padrão definido para importação.')</script>");
else
{
//Inicio da validação dos dados inseridos na planilha
int numLinhas = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
//Validação básica necessária para importação. PS: NumLinhas-1 porque o arquivo tem a última linha com total, que é inútil à importação.
VerificacaoPreliminar((numLinhas - 1), ds);



//Inicio da rotina de repetição para leitura de todas as linhas, iniciando na célula B6
if (!arquivoInvalidado)
{

                                    //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "Carregando...", "<script>document.getElementById('progresso').style.width = '30%';</script>");
//Verifica se existe mais de 1 interessado com mesmo CPF cadastrado, salva os interessados inexistentes e altera os cadastros q tem interessados duplicados.
this.ValidaDuplicidadeInteressado();

for (int i = 5; i < (numLinhas - 1); i++)
{
List<Processo> listaProcessoExistente = new List<Processo>();
Processo processo = null;
Interessado interessado = new Interessado();      

                                        //busca o processo pelo nº judicial anterior ou atual
if (!ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString().Equals(""))
processo = aplProcesso.consultarPorNProcessoER(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString());
if (processo == null)
{
if (!ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString().Equals(""))
processo = aplProcesso.consultarPorNProcessoER(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString());
}
                                        //busca o interessado por cpf/cnpj
                                        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[7].ToString().Length == 14)
   interessado = aplInteressado.ConsultarPorCPF(AuxiliarCPF_CNPJ.DesformataCPF(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[7].ToString()));
                                        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[7].ToString().Length == 18)
                                            interessado = aplInteressado.ConsultarPorCPF(AuxiliarCPF_CNPJ.DesformataCNPJ(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[7].ToString()));
if (processo != null)
{  
                                            //se o processo não for nulo busco todos procinter relacionados a ele
                                            List<ProcessoInteressado> listaprocinter = aplProcessoInteressado.consultarPorIdProcesso(processo.Codigo);
                                            if(listaprocinter.Exists(o=>o.Interessado == interessado))
                                                log.Append("O interessado informado na linha " + (i + 1) + " foi adicionado novamente ao processo " + processo.NumProcessoJudicial + " <br>");
                                            //foreach(var item in listaprocinter)
                                            //{
                                            //    if (item.Interessado == interessado)
                                            //        log.Append("O interessado informado na linha " + (i + 1) + " foi adicionado novamente ao processo " + processo.NumProcessoJudicial + " <br>");                                                 
                                            //}
                                            setProcInter(processo, interessado, ds, i);                                                                               
}
else
{
//Novo Processo - 6.3
processo = new Processo();

processo.Interessado = interessado;

processo.NumProcessoJudicial = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString().Trim();
processo.RenunciaCredito = "N";
processo.Situacao = new AplSituacao().ConsultarPorId(1);
processo.HonorarioDativo = "S";
processo.Reclamado = new AplReclamado().buscaItem(2);
processo.TipoDocumento = new AplTipoDocumento().buscaItem(4);
processo.TipoProcesso = "O";
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[5].ToString().Contains("juizado"))
processo.Tribunal = new AplTribunal().buscaItem(71);
else
processo.Tribunal = new AplTribunal().buscaItem(3);
processo.NaturezaDespeza = new AplNaturezadeDespesa().buscaItem(3);

                                            VaraExecucao vara = new VaraExecucao();
                                            if (!ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString().Equals("") && !ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[5].ToString().Equals(""))
                                            {
                                                List<VaraExecucao> listaVaraComarca = aplVaraExecucao.ConsultarPorNomeVaraNomeComarca(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[5].ToString().Trim(), ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString().Trim());
                                                if (listaVaraComarca.Count != 0)
                                                {

                                                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString().Equals(""))
                                                    {
                                                        vara = listaVaraComarca.Find(o => o.NumeroVara == null);
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        vara = listaVaraComarca.Find(o => o.NumeroVara == int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString().Trim()));
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            if (vara != null && vara.Codigo != 0)
                                            {
                                                processo.VaraExecucao = vara;
                                            }
                                            aplProcesso.gravar(processo);
aplLog.LogarAtividade(aplUsuario.buscaPorLogin(ObterUsuarioAutenticado().Login), "Importação do processo de número judicial: " + processo.NumProcessoJudicial
+ ". Interessado: " + processo.Interessado.Nome + " - " + processo.Interessado.CPF_CNPJ + ". Tribunal "
+ processo.Tribunal.NomeTribunal + ".", DateTime.Now);
//log.Append("O processo " + processo.NumProcessoJudicial + " informado na linha " + (i + 1) + " foi cadastrado com sucesso. <br>");

setProcInter(processo, interessado, ds, i);
}
}//Fim For
                                    //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "Carregando...", "<script>$('#progressbar').progressbar({value: 70});</script>");
                                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "Carregando...", "<script>document.getElementById('progresso').style.width = '60%';</script>");

if (listaGravarProcInter.Count != 0)
{
foreach (ProcessoInteressado item in listaGravarProcInter)
{
aplProcessoInteressado.salvar(item);
}
}
if (listaLogsAuditoria.Count != 0)
{
foreach (var item in listaLogsAuditoria)
{
aplLog.LogarAtividade(aplUsuario.buscaPorLogin(ObterUsuarioAutenticado().Login), item, DateTime.Now);
}
}
logimportacao.Visible = true;
loglbl.Text = log.ToString();
                                    //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "Carregando...", "<script>document.getElementById('progresso').style.width = '100%';</script>");
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "Alerta", "<script>alert('Arquivo importado com sucesso. Verifique o log na tela. ')</script>");
}
else
{
logimportacao.Visible = true;
loglbl.Text = log.ToString();
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "Erro", "<script>alert('Arquivo não importado. Verifique o log de erros na tela. ')</script>");
}

}
}
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara o Datatable consume muito recurso de memoria, vc poder criar uma classe apenas com as propriedades do arquivo que quer pesistir no banco, e usar a Uma lista para armazenar do tipo da sua classe, e na parte de acesso ao banco pode usar tanto o ADO que é o mais rapido na questão de acesso a dados, quanto o Dapper que é um framework muito bom e rapido: 
Exemplo da classe com as propriedades:

```
 public class Arquivo
{
    public int IdArquvio { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Exemplo da lista tipada:

```
List<Arquivo> listaArquivo = new List<Arquivo>();
```

coloquei aqui de uma forma bem resumida mas se nao entender só avisar que melhoro!

Comment: Jhonatas, entendi mais ou menos amigo, a minha dúvida é como aplicar isso no meu código. Teria algum e- mail para eu te enviar? porque por aqui não saiu legal. Mas estou com dúvida como irei alterar isso, como irá entrar dentro do meu código. etc.

Comment: meu email é jhonatas.silva1909@gmail.com me manda email que tento te ajudar nisso.

Comment: Beleza jhonatas, eu te mando o email. Realmente estou precisando de ajuda mesmo. Obrigado!

Comment: Te mandei um e- mail amigo

Comment: Não consegui entender, pessoal alguém pode me ajudar?